# Trying to capture value of a button and use ajax to submit a query

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have two buttons in a form. The update button updates the data and works fine. I am trying to implement a delete button that will delete the record based on which ever number is echoed in the button attribute value. Right now it is not doing anything.

```
<form id="update_form" action="" method="post">
<button id="update" type="submit" value="update">Update</button>   
<button id="unprocess" type="button" value="'.$order_no.'">DEL</button>  
</form>
```

My Jquery

```
$("#unprocess").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
             url: 'unprocess.php',
             data: $(this).val(value),
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (data) {
                 $(".error").css('display','none');
                 $(".success").css('display','block');
                 $('#search').focus();
             },
             error: function(data){
                 $(".success").css('display','none');
                 $(".error").css('display','block');
             }

         });

     });
```

My Query:

```
$order = $_POST['value'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE ord_no = $order";
    $query = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
```

I made the changes on line data:$(this).val(value), now the browser is at least capturing the value of the button, but it is not being passed to the query. any ideas

Comment: Just use `$(this).val()`;

Comment: This did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `data: { value: $(this).val() }` instead of  `data: $(this).serialize("value")`

Comment: I made the changes on line data:$(this).val(value), now the browser is at least capturing the value of the button, but it is not being passed to the query. any ideas

Comment: Use data: { value: $(this).val() }

Comment: I also changed it to how yours looks. I am getting a Param passed through. although my query is not being executed.

Comment: Try to print  $_POST['value'] in unprocess.php and check whether its receiving

Comment: the value is coming through to unprocess.php, I think my connection may be wrong one second.

Comment: OK All is working now that my connection is correct. data: { value: $(this).val() } is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem:

(1) As a test, echo back the value from PHP to make sure you have the right thing.

**PHP side**

```
<?php
    $v = $_POST["value"];
    die ($v);
```

**AJAX success function:**

```
alert(data); 
return false;
```

Then, (2) Create a standalone version of your PHP file with hard-coded values. See if it inserts into the database.

*You will quickly find your problem.*

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#unprocess").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
             url: 'unprocess.php',
             data: {order_no:this.value},
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (data) {
                 $(".error").css('display','none');
                 $(".success").css('display','block');
                 $('#search').focus();
             },
             error: function(data){
                 $(".success").css('display','none');
                 $(".error").css('display','block');
             }

         });

     });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/giantomakin/jh8d47kr/